# Matrix components and dot product

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl, opengl-3, dot-product

I have the following GLSL code:

```
uniform mat3x3 rgb2xyz = mat3x3(
    vec3(DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_XR, DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_XG, DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_XB),
    vec3(DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_YR, DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_YG, DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_YB),
    vec3(DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_ZR, DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_ZG, DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_ZB)
    );

vec3 RGBtoXYZ(vec3 rgb)
{
            // Works
    float X = DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_XR * rgb.r + DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_XG * rgb.g + DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_XB * rgb.b;
    float Y = DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_YR * rgb.r + DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_YG * rgb.g + DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_YB * rgb.b;
    float Z = DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_ZR * rgb.r + DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_ZG * rgb.g + DEFAULT_RGB2XYZ_ZB * rgb.b;
    return vec3(X, Y, Z);

            // Don't work
    /*float X = rgb2xyz[0][0] * rgb.r + rgb2xyz[0][1] * rgb.g + rgb2xyz[0][2] * rgb.b;
    float Y = rgb2xyz[1][0] * rgb.r + rgb2xyz[1][1] * rgb.g + rgb2xyz[1][2] * rgb.b;
    float Z = rgb2xyz[2][0] * rgb.r + rgb2xyz[2][1] * rgb.g + rgb2xyz[2][2] * rgb.b;
    return vec3(X, Y, Z);*/

            // Don't work
    /*return vec3(
        dot(rgb2xyz[0], rgb),
        dot(rgb2xyz[1], rgb),
        dot(rgb2xyz[2], rgb)
    );*/
}
```

The routine *RGBtoXYZ* have three code blocks (the last two commented). The first one work as expected, while the other commented ones does not work.

The problem is that I think they are equivalent. Why they are not?

Comment: You must give the definition of dot() as well.

Comment: See the comments on your answer. However, here it is: *float dot (genType x, genType y)*

Comment: Matrices in GLSL are **column-major**, btw.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Doesn't my code follow colum-major convention?

Comment: @Luca: No. `mat4[0]` is the first column of the matrix. Unless you are left-multiplying a vector by the matrix, you don't dot-product the columns of a matrix with the vector. You MADD the columns with the vector. Because you're doing manual left multiplication on a transposed matrix, your math works out correctly. Also, you don't need to manually multiply a matrix with a vector; the * operator will do it for you.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas So, is it faster to transpose the *rgb2xyz* matrix, and then return 'rgb * rgb2xyz'? Btw, I'm accessing to the matrix colums, using *matx3x3* as a storage for 3 *vec3*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I can't believe it!**

The Paul-Jan [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7161841/3) has resolved my issue!

Simply the GLSL compiler do not emit error on matrix initialization! *I can't believe it!*

---

I'm curious of your comments here, I'm thinking to open another question on this issue.